Smart CSS Mask using gradient and dynamic border radius
trying to make a css mask using the way the amazing Temani Afif shows here.
Unfortunately, what I need differs from what Temani shows in his examples.
Here is what I've manage to achieve:
CSS MASK  the edges are cut as much as the border radius I set.
I would like to keep the border radius as it is, but bring the cutout further into the shape like on the example below:
CSS Mask with border radius
I also managed to create the cutting effect on all the edges, again using the Temani Afif method, but as I can see on hes page the mask setup for all four corners is slightly different, which confuses me even more!
Is it possible at all to achieve the effect I've show on the image above with similar CSS mask setup for all four corners? I will be very appreciated for anyone's advice!
Thank you for your attention!
I have try this approach, borrowed from Temani Afif
// Cutted corner
    &[class*="card-cut"]{
        --r: var(--#{$pref}card-border-radius);
        --s: var(--#{$pref}card-border-radius);
        
        --_m:/calc(2*var(--r)) calc(2*var(--r))
            radial-gradient(#000 70%,#0000 72%) no-repeat;
    }

    &.#{$pref}card-cut-tl{
        mask:
        calc(var(--s) + var(--r)) 0 var(--_m),
        0 calc(var(--s) + var(--r)) var(--_m),
        radial-gradient(var(--s) at 0 0,#0000 99%,#000 101%) 
        var(--r) var(--r) no-repeat,
        conic-gradient(at calc(var(--s) + 2*var(--r)) calc(var(--s) + 2*var(--r)),
        #000 75%,#0000 0);
        padding-inline-start: 20%;
    }

    &.#{$pref}card-cut-tr{
        mask:
        radial-gradient(var(--s) at 100% 0,#0000 99%,#000 101%) calc(-1*var(--r)) var(--r) no-repeat,
        right calc(var(--s) + var(--r)) top 0 var(--_m),
        right calc(var(--s) + var(--r)) var(--_m),
        conic-gradient(at calc(100% - var(--s) - 2*var(--r)) calc(var(--s) + 2*var(--r)),
        #0000 25%,#000 0);
        padding-inline-end: 20%;
    }

    &.#{$pref}card-cut-br{
        mask:
        right 0 bottom calc(var(--s) + var(--r)) var(--_m),
        right calc(var(--s) + var(--r)) bottom 0 var(--_m),
        radial-gradient(var(--s) at 100% 100%,#0000 99%,#000 101%) 
        calc(-1*var(--r)) calc(-1*var(--r)) no-repeat,
        conic-gradient(from 90deg at calc(100% - var(--s) - 2*var(--r)) calc(100% - var(--s) - 2*var(--r)),
        #0000 25%,#000 0);
        padding-inline-end: 20%;
    }
    
    &.#{$pref}card-cut-bl{
        mask:
        calc(var(--s) + var(--r)) bottom var(--_m),
        bottom calc(var(--s) + var(--r)) left 0 var(--_m),
        radial-gradient(var(--s) at 0 100%,#0000 99%,#000 101%) 
        var(--r) calc(-1*var(--r)) no-repeat,
        conic-gradient(from 180deg at calc(var(--s) + 2*var(--r)) calc(100% - var(--s) - 2*var(--r)),
        #0000 25%,#000 0);
        padding-inline-start: 20%;
    }

